# Rails 3 Saving User Searches DataModel

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-postgresql, hstore

I am working on a piece of my app where the client is wanting the ability for user searches to be saved (these searches are completed by the user completing a set of dropdowns and then entering in a value in an input field).

I was curious to know if the use for an HSTORE could be beneficial here or should I just simply save out each piece of the search?

For Example (from a UI perspective):
User Selects a category, the next select is populated with stats tied to the selected category, the next select drop down is displayed which allows the user to select a predicate (greater than, less than, equal to, not equal to, etc) and then the input field is shown where the user can enter in their value they are searching for. If the user would like to add another search filter, they can click a button and then the user follows the same pattern as the first

The server side params look like this:

`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"FCvOdXuxtEhEchwDn8U2yaEPShfHW2VosgSoR8eSzV8=", "refresh"=>"1", "search"=>{"0"=>{"category"=>"1", "stat_type_id"=>"5", "predicate"=>"Greater Than", "q"=>"200", "type"=>"stat"}}, "unselected"=>""}`

These searches won't really be updated, when a user enters in a new search, it will be saved explicitly.

Once we figure out the best route for this project, I will post the code as the answer